# Android & iPhone UI Components comparison

Tags: android, iphone, ios, windows-phone-7, android-layout

I'm looking for a simple comparison of the native UI components of Android and iPhone, if more OS' are included like WP7 and Rim the better. But mainly to see the differences of the same features on iPhone and Android and features the one has but not the other and so on. I found this one:

http://cvil.ly/2011/01/27/comparing-common-iphone-and-android-ui-conventions/

which isn't going into depths about it. Has anyone seen something like this but a little bit deeper? I'd like to save some time from making one myself. But it would be good for developers who works with both to be able to show their clients the differences for the same features.

EDIT:
I would like to know if anyone has seen a comparison like this that I could use?

EDIT2:
If you develop a native application for both android and iPhone using only standard components for a customer. Wouldn't you like to be able to show the differences and what could easily be done for each OS? So I would like to know if anyone has seen a comparison of the standard UI components of each os?

Comment: If you develop a native application for both android and iPhone using only standard components for a customer. Wouldn't you like to be able to show the differences and what could easily be done for each OS? So I would like to know if anyone has seen a comparison of the standard UI components of each os?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't directly an answer to your question (UI Comparison), it's more of a resource for developers where it's shown what each WP class maps to in android and iphone.

http://wp7mapping.interoperabilitybridges.com/Home/Library?source=Android

http://wp7mapping.interoperabilitybridges.com/Home/Library?source=iPhone

Comment: Thanks, this is good too! But not exactly what I was looking for. More something graphical so anyone could see the difference between the same feature.

Comment: I'm not sure your question makes much sense. All UIs have pretty much the same UI elements (buttons, textboxes, lists, images etc.)
There's really no difference in what you can do between OS-es. The only difference is in the theme, but that change between versions of the same OS or even vendor specific. Android 2.3 and 4.0 have completely different theme, for the same user controls.

Comment: @Tomislav - I think the OP wants a simple rundown of the _names_ of the various standard controls (Spinner vs Picklist, etc) as well as a quick look at how they render. To my knowledge, though, no such list exists.